# how can i declare a dynamically allocated array global

Tags: arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault, declaration, global

how can i declare a dynamically allocated array global so that the array need not be initialized in every other function???

```
ushort  ***array_3D;
ushort **array_2D; 
extern int nexp;
int xarr,yarr; 
/***********intialization************/
void initialize()
{
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Hi");
    int ii,jj,kk;
    /*************** 2D array *********************/    
    // Allocate "main" array
    //
    array_2D = new ushort*[xarr];

    // Allocate each member of the "main" array
    //
    for (ii = 0; ii < xarr; ii++)
        array_2D[ii] = new ushort[yarr];
    /***********************************************/
    /************** 3D array ***********************/
    // Allocate "main" array
    //
    array_3D = new ushort**[nexp];

    // Allocate each member of the "main" array
    //
    for (ii = 0; ii < nexp; ii++)
        array_3D[ii]= array_2D;

    /***********************************************/
    return;
}

/**************some other function***************/
void foo
{
    int ii,kk,jj;
    int src_buffer[200];
    status = 0;         /* initialize status before calling fitsio routines */
    for (jj = 0; jj < naxes[1]; jj++)
        for (ii = 0; ii < naxes[0]; ii++)
        {
            src_buffer[i]=int(rand());
            array_2D[jj][ii]=int(src_buffer[n]);
            array_3D[kk][jj][ii]= int(src_buffer[n]);
        }
}
```

when i compile the above program it compiles without any problems.... but when i run de program i get segmentation fault when i call "foo". Help needed urgently. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to make every entry in `array_3D` point to the exact same 2D array? I'm guessing not. (But this can't be the cause of your segfault.)

Your code doesn't indicate how `xarr`, `yarr`, `nexp` and `naxes[...]` get their values. If they don't match up correctly -- if e.g. `naxes[0]` is bigger than `yarr` -- then `foo` will be trying to access things past the end of what you allocated.

Function `foo` uses `i` as an index into `src_buffer`, but `i` is not defined. If you have a global variable called `i`, please change that *right now*. If it's meant to say `ii` then, again, if `naxes[0]` is bigger than 200 then you'll write past the end of `src_buffer`.

Function `foo` uses `n` as an index into `src_buffer`, but `n` is not defined. If you have a global variable called `n`, then again please change it. Otherwise, what's `n` meant to be?